# Using Java 1.7 without maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, linux, maven, linux-mint

Is there any way I can force maven to compile using java 1.7 standard without using the maven-compiler-plugin? I have read about the JAVA_HOME being not set properly, but I don't think this is the case.
I have added the following line in the mvn script:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Below is the output of mvn --version

> > Apache Maven 3.0.4
> >
> > Maven home: /usr/share/maven
> >
> > Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
> >
> > Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
> >
> > Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
> >
> > OS name: "linux", version: "3.11.0-12-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"

One problem would be that $JAVA_HOME is set to /usr/lib/jvn/java-7-oracle while manven reports it to be $JAVA_HOME/jre.

The question is is there a way to configure maven tu use java 1.7 (similar to javac -target 1.7) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may configure the compiler plugin by passing appropriate `-D...` arguments when invoking maven. In your case this might be

```
mvn -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.7 compile
```

But i'd consider this an antipattern, as this makes your build dependent on additional parameters which must be documented. It is way better to define a proper configuration in some parent pom.

See [compiler:compile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) for complete description of the maven-compiler-plugin

Comment: and even this way OP would be using maven-compiler-plugin, so I don't see a (supported) way around it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you are right; but i supposed the OP wanted to avoid configuring the plugin, for whatever reason...

Comment: Yes, that might be. Or, to be exact, wanted to avoid configuring the plugin in pom - you're configuring it here as well, just through command line.

Comment: You are right, I expressed myself badly. I wanted to avoid configuring the plugin in the pom. The reason for doing this the fact that I was working on an app containing more than 30+ poms. And it would have been to much of an overhead.

Answer (score 4):

> The question is is there a way to configure maven tu use java 1.7
>   (similar to javac -target 1.7) ?

There is a way, and that is by configuring maven-compiler-plugin. That is what Maven uses for compiling, so that's what you need to configure.

If you insist on using javac, see what [maven compiler plugin manual says](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/):

> Since 3.0, the default compiler is javax.tools.JavaCompiler (if you
>   are using java 1.6) and is used to compile Java sources. If you want
>   to force the plugin using javac, you must configure the plugin option
>   forceJavacCompilerUse.

but even in that case it would be also about configuring the maven-compiler-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html, it looks like you can set these properties can be set without "poluting" your pom.xml file by setting in the command line the properties maven.compiler.target and maven.compiler.source.

So, a command like below should solve your problem.
    mvn install -Dmaven.compiler.target=1.7 -Dmaven.compiler.source=1.7

The default version for these atributes is 1.5. 
You can also modify the mvn script and add in the exec line these two atributes.